# Terraform vSphere Slow Boot

Tags: ubuntu, terraform, vsphere

This is my first try at creating a vSphere VM using terraform. The VM does successfully create, but takes 7 mins to complete. Here are the steps I've taken.

- Manually upload an Ubuntu 16.04 ova.
- Manually convert the image to a template.
- Manually create a VM from the template through the GUI. It takes
  about 20 seconds for the VM to start.
- Create the VM using terraform pointing to the template. This takes 7 
  mins.

Using terraform the VM boot sequence progresses the same as the manually created VM and then hangs at the below message for approximately 6 and half minutes.

```
[   12.109016] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
```

The error message repeats about 6 times for both the manual and the terraform VM creation. But during the manual creation, it moves to the login prompt almost immediately. During the terraform creation, it hangs at this message for about 6 and half minutes and then moves on to the login prompt. Any idea why it is hanging during the terraform creation?

**intance.tf**

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "hellovm" {
  name = "hellovm2"
  vcpu = 1
  memory = 1024
  datacenter = "Lab09-Datacenter01"

  network_interface {
    label = "Lab09-NetA"
  }

  disk {
    template = "${var.vmtemp}"
    type = "thin"
    datastore = "${var.vmdatastore}"
  }
}
```

**terraform apply stdout**

```
Macbook12:concoursebootstrap steve$ terraform apply
vsphere_folder.concourse-base: Refreshing state... (ID: Lab09-Datacenter01/VirtualMachines)
 vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Refreshing state... (ID: hellovm)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Creating...
  datacenter:                             "" => "Lab09-Datacenter01"
  detach_unknown_disks_on_delete:         "" => "false"
  disk.#:                                 "" => "1"
  disk.3867083049.bootable:               "" => ""
  disk.3867083049.controller_type:        "" => "scsi"
  disk.3867083049.datastore:              "" => "nfs-lab09-vol1"
  disk.3867083049.iops:                   "" => ""
  disk.3867083049.keep_on_remove:         "" => ""
  disk.3867083049.key:                    "" => "<computed>"
  disk.3867083049.name:                   "" => ""
  disk.3867083049.size:                   "" => ""
  disk.3867083049.template:               "" => "ubuntu-16.04-server-cloudimg-amd64"
  disk.3867083049.type:                   "" => "thin"
  disk.3867083049.uuid:                   "" => "<computed>"
  disk.3867083049.vmdk:                   "" => ""
  domain:                                 "" => "vsphere.local"
  enable_disk_uuid:                       "" => "false"
  linked_clone:                           "" => "false"
  memory:                                 "" => "1024"
  memory_reservation:                     "" => "0"
  moid:                                   "" => "<computed>"
  name:                                   "" => "hellovm"
  network_interface.#:                    "" => "1"
  network_interface.0.ip_address:         "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface.0.ipv4_address:       "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface.0.ipv4_gateway:       "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface.0.ipv4_prefix_length: "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface.0.ipv6_address:       "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface.0.ipv6_gateway:       "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface.0.ipv6_prefix_length: "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface.0.label:              "" => "Lab09-NetA"
  network_interface.0.mac_address:        "" => "<computed>"
  network_interface.0.subnet_mask:        "" => "<computed>"
  skip_customization:                     "" => "false"
  time_zone:                              "" => "Etc/UTC"
  uuid:                                   "" => "<computed>"
  vcpu:                                   "" => "1"
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (50s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (1m0s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (1m10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (1m20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (1m30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (1m40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (1m50s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (2m0s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (2m10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (2m20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (2m30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (2m40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (2m50s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (3m0s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (3m10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (3m20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (3m30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (3m40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (3m50s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (4m0s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (4m10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (4m20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (4m30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (4m40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (4m50s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (5m0s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (5m10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (5m20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (5m30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (5m40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (5m50s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (6m0s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (6m10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (6m20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (6m30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (6m40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (6m50s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (7m0s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (7m10s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (7m20s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (7m30s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Still creating... (7m40s elapsed)
vsphere_virtual_machine.hellovm: Creation complete (ID: hellovm)

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

**ubuntu dmesg**

[image: ubuntu dmesg]

**terraform trace output after VM is created and it is waiting for boot**

[image: terrafrom trace output]

**The rest of the terraform output. Several minutes of repeating logs then the following**

[image: terraform trace output part 2]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that you are having issues working with the vSphere provider!

From what I can see in the logs and by looking at your config, it might be because the VM does not necessarily have an IP address when it starts up. The Terraform vSphere provider currently waits for all interfaces to have network connectivity (reported through VMware tools) before it proceeds with reading the state of the virtual machine. This is the case on VM creation as well, so this is more than likely the cause of your issue (especially judging from the long wait after the `waiting for interfaces to appear` message is shown in the logs).

Looking at your configuration, I see no `ipv4_address` is assigned in the TF code, which means that Terraform will send a VM customization specification that tells the interface to use DHCP. If you don't have DHCP on your network, that could be part of the problem.

What I would recommend:

- If you don't have DHCP on the network you are working with, assign an IP address to the virtual machine using the [`ipv4_address`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/r/virtual_machine.html#ipv4_address) and related options, and try applying again. You can also install DHCP on the network in question as well to get around having to assign an IP address in TF code.
- Make sure that the VM has VMware tools installed. You can also install the `open-vm-tools` package on Ubuntu as well.
- Finally, if you are still having issues, you can check the VM's customziation logs - these can be found on the OS at `/var/log/vmware-imc/toolsDeployPkg.log`. [More info on Linux customization](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-7EF678CD-3BB0-4AA8-8430-17C657F0CD40.html).

Let me know if this fixes the issue for you!

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I'll give it a try and post the results.

Comment: Hi vancluever, we tried changing the IP assignment to a static value trying to remove that piece and we had no change in deploy time. After reviewing the the logs in toolsDeployPkg.log there were no timestamps associated to actions making it difficult to see a cause in the output. Do you have any other suggestions to see what is happening between the kernel startup process and the display of the login prompt

Comment: @ptsw sorry for the radio silence on this issue! I just wanted to mention that we released version 0.3.0 of the plugin today which changes the customization and network waiter behaviors significantly, so you might want to give that a go! In addition, if neither of those changes fix things for you, you might want to skip the waiter altogether which is now possible by setting the new [`wait_for_guest_net`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/r/virtual_machine.html#wait_for_guest_net) option to `false`. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks for the info. We got around the problem by using a different image. It appears there's something specific to the image we were using that caused it to hang. We never determined the root cause. @ecoles debugged it for a while. He may have something to add.